# Add more children to Wrap widget in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some `Buttons` wrapped inside a `Card` and I need to add more when I have to.

I tried with `Wrap.children.add` but it doesn't work, no error displayed, nothing changes.

Do you know how I can solve this?
I'm new in Flutter and dart so maybe I'm doing something stupid, I know.
I created a global variable called `_MyWrap` and my idea is to add `Buttons` to it when a Button is pressed.
"_getrandomButton" creates a new Button with a text inside(language) and "addRaisedButton" uses that function to create and add buttons to "Wrap" when the button is pressed.
A button that creates other "Buttons" inside a Wrap, this is it.

Code :

```
Wrap _MyWrap = new Wrap (children: <Widget>[]);
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
.
.
.
child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
             _addLanguage(),
            ],
.
.
.
Widget _addLanguage(){

RaisedButton _getrandomButton(String language){
   //creates a RaisedButton
  }
Future addRaisedButton(String name_) async{
  setState(() {
    _MyWrap.children.add(_getrandomButton(name_));
  });
}
.
.
.
child : RaisedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          addRaisedButton("English");
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep a List of names.
And in the build render the names List.
Then setState just add a new name to the list of names.
A new build is triggered and it will take the new list of names.

Comment: Ok and with the list of names I'll create the wrap right?

Comment: @MichealRoss yes you create the Wrap directly in the build method using the names List.